# Sporadic failure visual studio debugging C# code using VB.net library

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have trouble debugging a Windows application that uses some VB.net dlls. below a sample code

```
 dba = _DataAccessService.GetDataAccess(<<Connection String>>);

                parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
                parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@parameter1", 
                     FeedbackGenerator.Properties.Settings.Default.parameter));

                retVal = dba.GetDataSet(CommandType.Text, query.ToString(), parameters);
```

Dba is an instance of a wrapper class for DataAccess class (written in VB.net, It is working without any error since 5 years, even working in production with no complaint) every time it fails at different lines. funny thing is it does not throw any exception or any error, just visual studio stops debugging. I searched a lot in many forums, could not find anything relevant.
So far I have performed

1. Verified the dlls compatibility versions.
2. Access to the database.
3. Target version of .net.
4. search every possible log i.e. event log, visual studio log.
5. verified C# version.
6. Able to reproduce the same issue in different developer m/c.
7. Verified no dependency is missing.

Is anybody ever face such an issue? If yes, Have you found any way to mitigate or root cause?

Here is the project configuration

```
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <ConfigFile>Debug.config</ConfigFile>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell with that much of information, probably some compatibility issues. Take a look at the example of using System.Collections.Immutable in Unity, it's theoretically compatible but in reality there's a whole lot of funny corruption happening when you debug the project.

Comment: I guess the vb.net dll is a .NET Assembly written to wrap around an unmanaged library. If that's the case then your unmanaged code is probably originating the error, which *can't* be handled by .NET, which causes a silent crash like you're experiencing. Usually the advice here is to contact the unmanaged library vendor. If you have that code, add some logging to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with the code Since it was a windows application. all the worker thread run as expected, however, in MainF0rm_load method had a "Finally" block which caused the main thread to exit(application.exit). which explained sporadic failure. I was looking at the wrong place. It is "Threading NOT managed properly issue" and not a .Dll compatibility issue